# python --> pyinstaller - .exe file will return "test returned -1"

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, pywinauto

[1]
The code is:

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *

# Create Tk instance
root = Tkinter.Tk(className="test")


# Open Notepad
def openNotepad():
    import pywinauto
    app = pywinauto.Application.start("notepad.exe")


# Add menu 
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
filemenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="01 File", menu=filemenu)
filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=openNotepad)

# Pack all
root.mainloop()
```

[2] 
The code works if I double click on .py file.

If I leave only the openNotepad() function, then .exe will work.

According to docs: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Supported-Packages, the pywinauto library is supported.

If I leave only the Tkinter snippet, the .exe will work.

Therefore please share what I am doing wrong or please suggest other python installer for python 2.7x.

Comment: Which version of PyInstaller do you use?

Comment: hello guys. I used pyinstaller 3.0 + python 2.7.10,  By commenting out the line starting with: excludedimports in files \PyInstaller\hooks\hook-PIL.py and hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py, the problem was solved. I hope this will help others.

Comment: Great! Please answer your own question and mark as accepted to indicate it for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By commenting out the line starting with: excludedimports in files \PyInstaller\hooks\hook-PIL.py and hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace every `exit()`, `quit()`, or `os._exit()` with `sys.exit()`.
I see that you don't have any of these in your code but somebody else might find this advice to be useful.

My versions: python3.4, pyinstaller3.1.1